# Updating multiple PDF Form fields with the same name

Tags: java, itext, pdfstamper

I have a PDF Form generated using Apache OpenOffice Draw. The form has multiple text boxes with the same name. Is there a way to update all the fields with different data?

Best Regards,
Chandra.

Comment: In the pdf Format multiple fields with the same name are considered as multiple visualizations of the same field. Thus, even if you find a way to prepare the pdf to show different contents in those fields, the next program to process that pdf may immediately (or when starting to edit the Form in it) change your file to show the same value in them. Thus, i would propose fixing the pdf to not contain accidentally fields with identical names.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the quick response.
However, I have a requirement where I am getting a list of names (Strings) and I need to populate it to a list field of the PDF. I see there is no way doing it using iText. Please suggest any alternate ways of doing it.

Comment: My suggestion is to repair the pdf. If those fields are required to have different contents, then that PDF is broken.

Comment: +1 for Michael. Read the PDF specification and you'll understand why. An alternative would be to get the positions of all the widgets, remove the original (single) field and add multiple (new) fields (one for each widget). That would fix the form (and it's easy to achieve with iText).